# Strategy in solving linear equations with 3 unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I have an equation with this form:
$ A x + B y + C z = N$

$A$, $B$, $C$, and $N$ are known.

$A$, $B$, $C$, $N$, $x$, $y$, and $z$  are positive integers $>= 0$.

I need to find out values of $x$, $y$, $z$ that satisfy the equation.

Unless $N$ is a multiple of any of the coefficients, I cannot think of a way to solve this equation without brute-force trial and error.

What strategy should I use to solve this kind of linear equation?

Comment: As N must be a multiple of c:=gcd(A, B, C), you can first divide by c, which might help some. But probably you knew this already.

Comment: The upper bounds for $x,y,z$ are $N/A$, $N/B$, $N/C$. Are they  big? $A$,$B$,$C$ are probably not factors of $N$, otherwise you would get a solution immediately. Or you need all solutions?